# Basic http authentication and remove the prepend text username:password@ from the Static content (i.e image/js/css) url

Tags: security, http, authentication, web, basic-authentication

I have site where user need to get http basic authentication prior to access the url lets say `www.mybasicauthurl.com`. Basic authentication can be passed in either way

1. Browse the url and enter the username, password on the pop-up if not done already.
2. Access the url as: username:password@www.mybasicauthurl.com

Now I use approach #2 supply the basic auth credential via url itself. This works fine and I can able to see the legitimate web page but
When I open firebug and see the all loaded static files it shows me something like

```
http://username:password@www.mybasicauthurl.com/static/jquery/jquery.js
http://username:password@www.mybasicauthurl.com/static/css/styles.css
http://username:password@www.mybasicauthurl.com/static/image/image1.png
```

Please note the prepend text `username:password@` in the url. I don't want that I just want these static files to be loaded normally like

```
http://www.mybasicauthurl.com/static/css/styles.css
```

I don't know if this is something done by the `browser` or `apache` server.
Would be appreciated even if share some useful link that I missed to google.

Comment: Nothing to do with the server. It's what your response contains.

Comment: I have relative static path in the html file and seems something been done either by apache or browser.

Comment: "*relative*" to what??

Comment: relative to `base_url`. I am loading the script as 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/css/styles.css"></script>

Comment: Just to add further, When I run this on console `window.location.hostname` I get output as `www.mybasicauthurl.com`.

Comment: I think this is just cosmetic issue in the browser.  It has to synthesise a URL to display for the other resources based on what it thinks the base of the page is.  If you look in wireshark, you will see what is actually sent and received and you can satisfy yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid HTTP auth on static resources, the best thing to do is to remove it **server-side**.

That means static resources would ba available without authentication, but if nothing important is present in the static resources, that's good.

Should be something like that:

```
# Apache < 2.4
<Location /static>
    Satisfy Any
    Allow from all
</Location>

# Apache >= 2.4
<Location /static>
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

**Another point**. If the thing you do not like is the presence of **username:password** in the HTML source, that's effectively quite bad, and depending on the browsers versions it may or may not be supported (tends to be removed). That's a clear text information, could be intercepted or stored on the browser cache. **But** you are also using `http://` and not `https://` and this is even worse. The **username:password** is **transmitted in clear text for each request of the browser**, everybody can read this information!

When using Basic HTTP Authentification you **must** use HTTPS. Credentials are transmitted with a simple base64 *encoding*, it's just an ascii-7-trick encoding (like utf-8 is an encoding). So if you want to protect this username/password information you will also need HTTPS.